Pasar datos de un array de Javascript a php e insertarlos en la base de datos de Mysql
Buenas soy nuevo en javascript y estoy haciendo un proyecto de biblioteca , estuve avanzando bien hasta que me encontre con que tengo que enviar la lista de libros solicitados guardado en el array de js a php para luego insertarla en la base de datos y no eh podido siempre me sale Error al leer los datos JSON de la solicitud , me intente ayudar con alguna IA pero sin respuestas a mi problema, espero puedan ayudarme , gracias
.
function solicitarLibros() {
    let listaLibros = document.getElementById('listaLibrosSeleccionados');
    let libros = listaLibros.getElementsByTagName('li');
    let librosSolicitados = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < libros.length; i++) {
        let libroText = libros[i].textContent;
        let [titulo, autor] = libroText.split(' - '); // Suponiendo que el formato sea "Título - Autor"
        librosSolicitados.push({ titulo: titulo, autor: autor });
    }

    console.log('Libros solicitados:', librosSolicitados); // Verifica si se están obteniendo los datos correctamente

    // Enviar la lista de libros solicitados al servidor utilizando AJAX
    fetch('solicitudes.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ libros: librosSolicitados })
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.text();
            } else {
                throw new Error('Error al enviar la lista de libros solicitados');
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            alert('Lista de libros solicitados guardada correctamente');
            // Limpiar la lista de libros seleccionados
            // librosSeleccionados = [];
            // mostrarListaSeleccionados(); // Actualizar la lista en la interfaz
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

este es el php, donde eh añadido mensajes de error por todos lados para saber en que parte esta mal sin embargo me sale el mismo error Error al leer los datos JSON de la solicitud , la conexion a la base de datos esta bien y los datos de la tabla igual
<?php
include 'Conexion_db.php';

$conn = conectarDB();

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexión fallida: ". $conn->connect_error);
}

// Iniciar la sesión
session_start();

try {
    // Obtener el DNI del usuario autenticado
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT dni FROM usuarios WHERE usuario =?");
    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception("Error en la preparación de la consulta: ". $conn->error);
    }
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["usuario"]);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        throw new Exception("Error al ejecutar la consulta: ". $stmt->error);
    }
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // Verificar si se encontró al menos un usuario que coincida
    if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $id_usuario = $row['dni'];
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Error: No se encontró ningún usuario con el nombre de usuario proporcionado");
    }

    // Leer los datos JSON enviados en la solicitud
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if (!$json) {
        throw new Exception("Error al leer los datos JSON de la solicitud");
    }
    // Decodificar los datos JSON en un array asociativo
    $data = json_decode($json, true);
    if (json_last_error()!== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new Exception("Error al decodificar los datos JSON: ". json_last_error_msg());
    }
    // Ahora puedes acceder a los datos enviados
    if (!isset($data['libros'])) {
        throw new Exception("Error: No se recibieron los datos esperados");
    }
    $librosSolicitados = $data['libros'];

    // Preparar los datos para la inserción en la base de datos
    $fechaSolicitud = date('Y-m-d');
    $estado = 'Pendiente';

    // Preparar la consulta SQL para insertar múltiples registros
    $sql = "INSERT INTO solicitudes (dni_usuario, titulo_libro, autor_libro, fecha_solicitud, estado) VALUES ";
    $params = [];
    foreach ($librosSolicitados as $libro) {
        $titulo = $libro['titulo']?? '';
        $autor = $libro['autor']?? '';
        $sql.= "(?,?,?,?,?),";
        $params[] = $id_usuario;
        $params[] = $titulo;
        $params[] = $autor;
        $params[] = $fechaSolicitud;
        $params[] = $estado;
    }
    // Eliminar la última coma y espacio agregados
    $sql = rtrim($sql, ", ");

    // Preparar la consulta con marcadores de posición
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception("Error en la preparación de la consulta: ". $conn->error);
    }

    // Vincular los parámetros a la consulta
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("issss", count($librosSolicitados)),...$params);

    // Ejecutar la consulta
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        throw new Exception("Error al ejecutar la consulta: ". $stmt->error);
    }

    // Imprimir mensaje de éxito
    echo "Todos los libros solicitados han sido guardados correctamente.<br>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Imprimir mensaje de error
    echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
}
?>


y cual es el error o problema???

Ok, supongo guardas los libros seleccionados en un input o algo así con el ID 'listaLibrosSeleccionados', al entrar a JS los separas por li, lo que veo es que te estás trayendo todo el html, lo que yo haría sería algo como esto:
let listaLibros = document.getElementById('listaLibrosSeleccionados');
let libros = listaLibros.getElementsByTagName('li').value;
let variable = listaLibros.getElementsByTagName('li').lenght;

for(let i = 0; i < variable; i++)

Ya de después de esto mando todos los datos al php el cual recibiría con algo así:
$libros = $_POST['libros'];

Checa bien tu sintaxis veo algunos errores. Espero te sirva, el ciclo for se encargará de mandar uno por uno, ya si lo quieres recibir todo como una cadena de texto en php puedes mandarlo todo de una y al recibirlo desconcatenarlo poniendo un caracter y con split.
